# socket.io application structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, model-view-controller, socket.io

Can anyone reccomend a clientside MVC framework for a socket.io application? Small, light and tight are my only reqs.

I have used backbone.js in a couple of work related projects and its great, although mainly structured for a REST interface not WebSockets.

Comment: +1 Good question. I've never used MVC for client-side but ExtJs 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already know backbone, there is no reason not to continue using it!

[How to use backbone.js with websockets/socket-io/nowjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657968/how-to-use-backbone-js-with-websockets-socket-io-nowjs)