# Creating live collections in backbone.js?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone.js-collections

Im creating a basic backbone app that should support multiple usrers, and i eould like my collection views to update for all users when any of thrm make a change to the collection.

I'm doing the following :

in my Views :

```
/*Collection view
- - - - - - -*/
App.Views.Contacts = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'tbody',
    wrapper : $('#contacttable'),
    initialize: function() {

        // custom events
        vent.on('hideparent', this.hideMe,this);
        vent.on('showparent', this.showMe,this);

        // standard events
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.addOne);
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.addAll);
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'all', this.render);

        // Load the collection data
        this.collection.fetch({reset:true});
    },
    render: function() {
        // publish view status
        vent.trigger();
        // append the list view to the DOM
        $('#contacttable').append(this.el);
        return this;
    },
    addAll : function() {
        this.collection.each( this.addOne, this);
    },
    addOne: function(model) {
        var contactView = new App.Views.Contact({ model: model});
        this.$el.append(contactView.render().el);
    },
    showMe: function() {
        this.wrapper.show();
    },
    hideMe: function() {
        this.wrapper.hide();
    }
});

/*Single view
- - - - - - - */
App.Views.Contact = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'tr',
    template: template('singlecontact'),
    events: {
        'click a.delete' : 'deleteContact'
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.model.on('destroy', this.unrender, this); // doing this so item is only removed visually if its actually destroyed
        this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) );
        return this;
    },
    deleteContact: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.model.destroy();
    },
    unrender: function() {
        this.remove(); 
    }
});
```

in my router :

this works for adding and editing **but not deleting** which is a problem 1.  It also doesnt feel particularly right.

```
contactList: function() {
    vent.trigger('app:contacts');
    if (typeof App.AllContactsView == 'undefined') {
        App.AllContactsView = new App.Views.Contacts({ //init method runs now
            collection : App.contacts
        });

            // checking for updates
        function updateContacts() {
            App.AllContactsView.collection.fetch({merge:true });
        }

        setInterval(updateContacts, 1000);

    } else {
        App.AllContactsView.collection.fetch({add:true,remove:true});
    }

    ViewManagerTwo.showView(App.AllContactsView,true,false, false);
    return App.AllContactsView;
},
```

is there a **native way** - ideally better than this to update the collections live?

Comment: For this type of functionality, you'd be better served by looking into websockets.

Comment: okay cool, I'm currently building a basic app, firstly to learn BB and secondly to build out a basic framework for myself, I'm doing it with a pretty quick and dirty laravel backend, but will be moving on to node express and sails which supports sockets quite well it looks like.  If you can give me an answer below with a little more info on using sockets in BB on the front end I'd be highly appreciative.

Comment: want to answer this so I can close it off ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some info on using websockets as the transport layer in Backbone, which should get you going:

http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2012/04/19/decoupling-backbone-apps-from-websockets/

[How to use backbone.js with websockets/socket-io/nowjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657968/how-to-use-backbone-js-with-websockets-socket-io-nowjs)

Comment: thanks, the stack overflow question is good discussion worth checking out.